# Word for the sounding of a phone notification (not a call)

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

"*The phone is ringing*" refers to an incoming call, so saying that is misleading when you've gotten a text/notification. Is there a different word to use in that sentence ("The phone is _______") to mean "the phone is making the sound of receiving text/notification"?

Answer (score 3):

***Beeping***

A *beep* is

> a short, relatively high-pitched tone produced by a horn, electronic device, or the like as a signal, summons, or warning. ([Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/beep))

Here is an example provided by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/beep):

> Then phones started ***beeping*** with news alerts.
> *The Guardian* (2016)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for entries in a menu, say to set a particular sound for "incoming call" or "incoming text", then "Ringtone" and "Notification" are already well used.

For the **particular** sound which is set using those menus, generally it depends on what the sound is:

- Beep
- Ping
- Ding
- Knock

All are possibilities; each sounds different.

For a **generic** noise, *beep* is certainly used — for example in film subtitles when a message is received, or as used by the *Guardian* in [fev's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/608953/18696).

Comment: As you show, the sound is variable, so the label of the sound depends on the choice, which is assignable.

Comment: While the sound is variable, "beep" would work well enough as a generic term, even if you have a recording of a baby laughing or the ringing of a gong as your notification.